# SSAS 2012 Using a dimension value to filter other dimension tables

Tags: ssas, dimension

I have a Customer table and several other dimension tables that contain a Customer Id.

What I'd like to have is the dimension tables filtered by the top level Customer selection.

So if I have:

**Customers**
Id | Name

**DimensionA**
Id | CustomerId | Value1
Id | CustomerId | Value2

**DimensionB**
Id | CustomerId | Value3
Id | CustomerId | Value4

**Fact**
Id | DimensionBId | FactValue1 ...
Id | DimensionBId | FactValue2 ...

..is it possible to have the CustomerId filtered and trickle down through the dimension values to the fact table?

Or, do I always need to relate Customer to Fact in the Dimension Usage? I can see how I could relate Customer to Fact via DimensionA, but I can only relate it with one intermediary table, not two or more.

Alternatively do I need to actually have CustomerId in the Fact table as well?

Any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 2):

It all depeneds on the schema you are using for your DataWarehouse.

I think that the **star schema** is the best option you have.

If you use it you need to have a customer_id in the fact table and link them through the dimension usage. The same holds for DimensionA and DimensionB (that is the Fact table needs to have a corresponding id for dimensionA and dimension B).

If you do this in that approach you need not have the customer id on either dimension A nor on dimension B. The link will be achieved through the Fact table.

Otherwise consider this: Do you really need 2 dimensions? Since the two dimensions are almost identical, wouldn't it be better if you added a new field called Type, Where type would be A and B in your datasource table, and add the type to your Hierarchy? That would solve a lot of problems and make your schema a lot more consistent!!!

Here is a link from the site of Ralph Kimball [Kimball's_Site_Link](http://www.kimballgroup.com/2000/04/10/design-tip-6-showing-the-correlation-between-dimensions/) explaining in a much better way than mine what is what. You will find the last paragraph very informative!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The dimensions there are greatly simplified for the question. Having the CustomerId on the fact table makes sense, but I need to keep it on the dimensions too as the dimension members relate to a given Customer. I was hoping that somehow I could join Customers to the facts *and* the dimensions to keep everything in context to a Customer.

Comment: If you place the customer id on the Fact table you will then be able to join customer id and dimension through the fact (SSAS will do this automatically). Example: CustomerDim -> FactSales <- DimensionA. The customer is joined to Dimension A for each Fact sales row that has the customerId and the DimAid on a single row.

Comment: Also bear in mind that SSAS is not a database. Everything is about the aggregation of the things you want to count. If customer - fact -dimension relationship does not exist, there is no (apparent) reason for the customer to be joined to the dimension! That is evident in the dimension usage tab where you can only join dimensions to their corresponding FactTables and not a dimension to another.